# Windows 7 on Asus F556UQ?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I want to install Windows 7 on the notebook Asus F556UQ. However, on the Asus website there are only drives for Windows 10 provided. Is there a possibility to get the neccesary drivers for Windows 7?

Comment: there is a reason ASUS doesn't provide those drivers. Your laptop has i5-6198DU for processor which means it's based on Skylake arch which doesn't support Windows 7.

Comment: @MustafaAKTAŞ skylake supports Win7, you mean Kaby Lake

Comment: @magicandre1981 wrong. windows 7 is generally not supported by skylake. only a selection of skylake based pcs support windows 7. asus' selection doesn't include this particular device :  https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1015905/

Comment: it shows support to at least 2018

Comment: So this means there is no possibility and I should install Win10 instead?